# How do I become root on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

I recently started doing Unix and Mac development, coming from a hardcore work environment in .NET. I am learning terminal use and how to `mkdir` and `ls` and `vim`, but it's all under my actual name.

I just bought a MacBook Pro Retina. My Unix account shows my name. But I need to login as root.

I tried this command in terminal to switch to root:

```
su - root
```

but it won't take my password, and I really don't know which password to provide?

Comment: try sudo su - root    You probably just want to run things with sudo instead of actually switching to root.

Comment: root isn't enabled on mac by default why do you need to be root?

Comment: If you are running linux on that macbook pro (which works perfectly fine) you should be able to use that command. However it requires the root password, not yours, since you have to prove that you are indeed permitted to act as that root user.

Comment: I've worked on mac and Linux for many years and I have very rarely needed to log in as root. Tell us what you're trying to do, and we'll tell you a better way (most likely use `sudo` instead).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should *actually* use `sudo -i` to start an interactive shell. Then, type your login password. It won't appear; that's okay. Keep typing, then press <kbd>Return</kbd>.

To exit the interactive shell, type `exit` or `^D` (that's <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, not <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>). You'll then be back in your normal terminal.

---

Regarding your original question: Use `sudo su`.

The `su` command grants you access to another user's account, but you need to know that user's password. Since `root` is disabled by default (and for good reason), and has no password, you can use `sudo`, which grants you elevated privileges for one command, to overrule that rule. When `sudo` prompts you for your password:

```
[sudo] password for huang:
```

just enter your password. It won't appear due to security reasons (so people can't see how long it is) but it is being entered. Press <kbd>Return</kbd> when done.

Comment: -1 for the unexplained passive aggression. I have no idea what alternative approach you're saying `sudo -i` is "*actually*" better than, or why, and nor do I know what change to the "*original*" question you're insinuating occurred (presumably inside of the grace period, and thus not appearing in the edit history?). Without those details, this answer is pretty incomprehensible. It sounds like you're saying `sudo su` is superior to `sudo -i` in some circumstances outlined in a no-longer-accessible revision, which is an obviously unhelpful way to frame the answer for future readers.

Answer (score 6):

OS Sierra

```
dsenableroot
```

More info: [How to Enable the Root User on Your Mac](https://www.maketecheasier.com/enable-root-user-mac/)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it helped tremendously to solve the conundrum after my introducing a syntax error in a sudoers file.  With my Linux memories, I thought my only way out of this was rebooting the MacBook, starting it in a rescue mode, mounting the disk and editing or removing the offensive file.

Answer (score 3):

Just type the following command:

```
sudo su
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This only works if you're an admin user, which you shouldn't be I think. Better create another user with admin rights. Whenever you need admin rights for installing software, you have to enter the login for an admin user.

Let's say you give this new admin user the name "huangadmin". It may be something else (like admin), but I don't think it's a good idea to give it the name "root".

Then, in the terminal, you need to use `su huangadmin`. The password for this account is requested, and then you're user huangadmin. Then you can use `sudo su` and become root.

Answer (score 0):

very simple command to run as sudo :

```
sudo -s what_ever_command_you_want
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default root user is disabled on Mac, you need to first enable root user on Mac.
Refer: https://www.dataneb.com/single-post/2018/08/29/How-to-enable-root-user-on-Mac

> From top left hand side, choose Apple menu () > System Preferences, then click Users & Groups (or Accounts).
>
> Click the lock icon , then enter an administrator name and password.
>
> After you unlock the lock. Click Login Options, right next to home icon.
>
> Now Click Join (or Edit), right next to Network Account Server. Now Click Open Directory Utility.
>
> Click lock icon in the Directory Utility window, then enter an administrator name and password.
>
> From the menu bar in Directory Utility: Choose Edit > Enable Root User, then enter the password that you want to use for the root user. You can enable/disable/change password for root user from here.
>
> Now go to Terminal and switch user to root and test.

Once root user password is set in Directory utilities. Type **su root** in your terminal and enter the password. Note local admin user password is not same as root user.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to `su` from your standard account, you need to add it to [`/etc/sudoers`](http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/06/add-user-sudoers-file-mac/).  This works regardless of the `root` account being enabled or not after you [created](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012) `root`'s password.

It will allow you to `sudo su`, `sudo -i`, or `sudo` any command (better); `su - root` or `su` never works from a standard account.

Needless to say, try this only if you really know what you're doing as a super user.